# What's a good .NET based blogging engine?

Tags: recommendations, blog, windows

What is a good .NET based blogging engine?

And why would you recommend it.

Comment: good how?  Can you rephrase so that this question can be answered in an objective manner?

Comment: @rchern - I was originally asking for a 'recommendation', but changed it to 'good' because it was more concise and communicated pretty much the same thing.

Comment: But "good" might depend on what criteria you have, and someone might recommend based on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [BlogEngine.Net](http://blogengine.codeplex.com/). If I recall, it can also be installed by the Web platform Installer.
Other features (quoted from the product page):

> - Multi-author support
> - Pingbacks and trackbacks
> - Event based for plug-in writers
> - Theming directly in master pages and user controls
> - Gravatar and coComments implemented
> - Live preview on commenting
> - Comment moderation
> - BlogML import/export
> - Extension model
> - Code syntax highlighting
> - Mono support
> - Full editing and creation of pages that are not posts
> - Extended search capabilities
> - Tag cloud
> - Self updating blogroll
> - Runs entirely on XML or SQL Server. Your choice.

And it's completely open source. I self compiled the version I used.

Answer (score 1):

I used [dasBlog](http://www.dasblog.info/) because it was really easy to customize, install, and it didn't need a database.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **[Subtext](http://subtextproject.com/)**. It can be easily installed using Web Platform Istaller. Subtext is an open source project licensed under the BSD license.

It's designed and written by **[Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/)** who is a Senior Program Manager at Microsoft responsible for ASP.NET MVC.

Features:

- Database storage for blog content
- Unlimited blogs
- Multiple categories per blog post
- Tag support
- Keyword expansion
- Plugin-based post editor (includes
  FCKeditor and FreeTextBox)
- MetaWeblog API support
- RSS 2.0/ATOM 1.0 syndication
- Comments
- Comment spam prevention
- Skins
- Single author per blog
- Single blog host administrator
- Trackback/pingback support
- BlogML import/export for content
- Search engine friendly URLs
- Image gallery
- Linkroll
- Gravatar and Identicon support